# How do I sign into Google using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, automation, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer and I am trying to sign into my Gmail account

URL: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/identifier?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=AddSession

Currently my code types into the email form and submits enter,
then when the page goes to the password screen, there is not way to write in the input for password. This may be because it is technically not a new page but the same. Either way I cannot seem to interact with this new page when I press enter on the email page.

I tried used a lot of the methods but to no avail.

```
const elementHandle = await page.$('input');
await elementHandle.type('dp-conference@digitalpulp.com');
  await page.click("#identifierNext");

//goes to new page
//this code does not work. 
const pw = await page.$('input[type="password"]');


page.on('load', () => console.log("Loaded: " + page.url()));
```

})

Comment: Use the minimal code below:

`await page.waitFor(_milliseconds_);`

Works for me well. I can post the code here if you need.

Answer (score 8):

This full script should work, please not this doesnt handle if you are logged in already or if your account uses 2-factor authentication, good luck

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false})
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  const navigationPromise = page.waitForNavigation()

  await page.goto('https://accounts.google.com/')

  await navigationPromise

  await page.waitForSelector('input[type="email"]')
  await page.click('input[type="email"]')

  await navigationPromise

  //TODO : change to your email 
  await page.type('input[type="email"]', 'youremail@gmail.com')

  await page.waitForSelector('#identifierNext')
  await page.click('#identifierNext')

  await page.waitFor(500);

  await page.waitForSelector('input[type="password"]')
  await page.click('input[type="email"]')
  await page.waitFor(500);

  //TODO : change to your password
  await page.type('input[type="password"]', 'yourpassword')

  await page.waitForSelector('#passwordNext')
  await page.click('#passwordNext')

  await navigationPromise

  //await browser.close()
})()
```

Comment: i think this doesn't work anymore gmail is blocking login with puppeteer , selenuim .... browser or app my not be secure, and i still didn't find any solution

Comment: @ABDELJALILAITETALEB did you ever find a way to login to google using any of those scraping tools (im personally looking for puppeteer)?

Comment: @justanotherguy you should be able to do that using puppeteer-extra check it out on github , this work for me

Comment: @ABDELJALILAITETALEB are you able to share any code? I have used puppeteer-extra with the Stealth option, but I seem to keep getting the same issue.

Comment: @justanotherguy this some i code i've used  https://gist.github.com/smartdev10/d7323163c8346c97a9625b18d04ebbc0

Comment: @ABDELJALILAITETALEB Thanks, I tried puppeteer-extra & it works great

Comment: @ABDELJALILAITETALEB can you elaborate how you run those two files?? they dont reference each other inside in any way

Answer (score 2):

This works for now... you can login once it loads like this.  Get's around fedex login restrictions too :) Thanks @ABDELJALILAITETALEB !!!

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth');
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());
doit = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox'], headless: false});
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://accounts.google.com');
}
doit();
```

Answer (score 1):

In this code, the waitForSelector('[type="password"]', { visible: true }) line waits for the password input field to become visible on the same page before proceeding with entering the password and clicking the "Next" button.

```
const express = require("express");
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const StealthPlugin = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");

puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin());

const { executablePath } = require("puppeteer");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());


(async () => {
    try {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        executablePath:executablePath(),
      });
     
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto("https://accounts.google.com/");
  
      await page.waitForSelector('[type="email"]');
      await page.type('[type="email"]', "you@email.com");
      await page.click("#identifierNext");
  
      // Wait for the password input field to appear
      await page.waitForSelector('[type="password"]', { visible: true });
      await page.type('[type="password"]', "password");
  
      await page.click("#passwordNext");
      await page.waitForNavigation();

      console.log("Login successful");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
    }
  })();
  
app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If a page load happens then the subsequent commands/scripts won't work as they aren't loaded properly. For that there's the [waitForNavigation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) method.

Your code will look something like:

```
const elementHandle = await page.$('input');
await elementHandle.type('dp-conference@digitalpulp.com');
await page.click("#identifierNext");

// Wait for next pageload
await page.waitForNavigation(waitOptions)
const pw = await page.$('input[type="password"]');
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by signup process manually on puppeteer running instance and logged in successfully on Gmail. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bro, I get it by adding an interval between instructions like this:

```
await page.goto('google-login-page-here')
await page.waitForTimeout(1000) // 1s interval
await page.waitForSelector('input[type="email"]')
await page.focus('input[type="email"]')
await page.keyboard.type('your-email-here', { delay: 50 })
await page.waitForTimeout(1000) // 1s interval
await page.click('next-button-selector-here')

await page.waitForTimeout(3000) // 3s interval
await page.waitForSelector('input[type="password"]')
await page.focus('input[type="password"]')
await page.keyboard.type('your-password-here', { delay: 50 })
await page.waitForTimeout(1000) // 1s interval
await page.click('next-button-selector-here')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly different from the others, and can be useful too. In puppeteer create a test and paste the following code:

```
    test('google_login', async () => {
           const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false})
           const page = await browser.newPage()
  
           await page.goto('https://accounts.google.com/')
           await page.waitForTimeout(1000) // 1s interval
           await page.waitForSelector('input[type="email"]')
           await page.focus('input[type="email"]')
           await page.keyboard.type('YOURMAIL', { delay: 50 })
           await page.waitForTimeout(1000) // 1s interval
           await page.click('#identifierNext')
           await page.waitForNavigation();
 
           await page.waitForSelector('input[type="password"]');
           await page.focus('input[type="password"]')
           await page.waitForTimeout(1000);

           await page.type('input[type="password"]', 'YOURPASS', { delay: 50 })
      
           await page.click("#passwordNext");
           await page.waitForNavigation();
           console.log('Succesfully logued');
```

On the file package.json at the end of the file add the following sentence:

```
     "scripts": {
         "start": "jest ."
       }
```

then simply test the code running on the console:

```
npm start
```